# Curl works but Postman doesn't

Tags: google-chrome, http, curl, chromium, postman

When I call my service end-point with curl, I get a response as expected:

```
> curl http://localhost:87/ping
> pong
```

But, when I use postman in chrome, it cannot get any response (see screenshot below):

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I can even get the contents using one and the same Chrome instance, by just opening the url directly... but Postman reports no response.

Comment: For me it's the opposite. Problem with curl, postman works

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: have you tried with Postman App ?

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue by uninstalling the postman app and reinstalling the postman extension.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I switched off the SSL certificate verification option under file->settings->general, and it fixed the issue.